# Does a revert trans man have to follow the rules in Islam for a woman

Tags: transgender

I have a friend who asked me a very important question that I can’t answer. For context he is a trans man that wants to revert to Islam, he asked me to teach him how to pray but he doesn’t know if he should wear a hijab while praying or not. Does he follow the rules Islam out for men or does he follow the rules for the woman. The question has been bugging me and I can’t seem to find an answer

Answer (score 3):

If she was a woman at birth then she remains a woman forever. If he was a man at birth he remains a man forever. He or She must follow the rules that apply to the assigned gender at birth.